# Significant value change after remove intercept in Linear model

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have implemented a linear regression with intercept and without an intercept:

```
TotalReview ~ Number_of_files + LOC
```

With intercept, I get the below output where `Number_of_files` variable is significant:

```
Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)     -5.279e+02  1.114e+02  -4.740  0.00515 **
LOC              7.045e-04  2.260e-03   0.312  0.76778   
Number_of_files  1.929e+00  6.026e-01   3.202  0.02395 *
```

Without Intercept, I get a very different output and `LOC` is suddenly significant:

```
Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
Number_of_files -0.760434   0.433852  -1.753   0.1302  
LOC              0.008528   0.003302   2.582   0.0416 *
```

Why does the significance of my variable change from `Number_of_files` to `LOC` after the intercept is removed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a statistics problem, not a programming one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively, what a regression does, is fitting a line in the "best possible way" through a cloud of data points. A coefficient in your regression output is the slope of this line. If the slope (coefficient) is zero, then (according to the regression logic) there is no relation between the dependent variable `y` and the independent variable `x`, i.e. the coefficient will be insignificant.

When you decide to remove the intercept from the fitted line, the slopes of the lines will change in an attempt to still fit the best possible line through the cloud of the data points. What you are seeing is exactly that: the coefficients of `LOC` and `Number_of_files` have changed dramatically.

In the image below you can see the impact in the case where you only have one independent variable (say, only `LOC`). As you can see, the slope of the blue line (no intercept) is much steeper than the slope of the red line (with intercept).

[image]

On a final note, unless you have a very good reason why your model should not contain an intercept, you should just keep the intercept.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes you are right. I should keep the intercept. But surprisingly if I remove the intercept then prediction more accurate rather than keep the intercept. Multiple R-squared value 0.939 in with intercept and 0.9928 value in without intercept. That's why I am confuse whether I should keep intercept or not?

Comment: You can check it this answer for more information https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-increases-r2-in-linear-mo